# Website Redirects but I did not allow it

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I've setup a website using WordPress and just noticed that the homepage redirects to a different section of the website with random characters.

Like www.yourdomain.com redirects to www.yourdomain.com/XYiOEL which is a 404. It changes, sometimes it is there, sometimes it is not. I've checked my .htaccess (newbie here) and I don't see anything that could cause this.

Help?

Comment: I've seen this exact thing before. Your site/server has been hacked. You'll want to contact your host, delete all your files and database, install WordPress fresh from http://wordpress.org and restore a database backup from before the problem began.

Answer (score 0):

See [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/) and [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and tell your host. Change all passswords. Scan your own PC. And see http://blog.sucuri.net/2011/08/timthumb-php-security-vulnerability-just-the-tip-of-the-iceberg.html